# how to do auto complete for twitter mention on iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, autocomplete

I am trying to develop an app which requires to compose a tweet. I can not figure out how to do the auto complete for twitter mention. For example, when users type "@a", the app needs to search all his friends starting with "a". I don't know which twitter api I can search/query to have the list of friends starting with specific characters.  I have been going though the twitter api but still no clue. I saw some twitter clients have this feature so it should be doable..

Many thanks in advance.

James

Comment: which twitter api are you using?

Comment: i am using sttwitter for iOS. i can use the official twitter api as well. but i didn't find a nice way to do that with the official tweeter api

Comment: Do you know how to request for the list of friends with a given user id (logged in user of course)?

Comment: Thank you Pavan. But the list of friends might have multiple pages and many many users.  i thought it is not efficient to get all friends and do the search again.

Comment: Dude, relax. I asked you if you knew how to get a simple array of the hundreds of friends that they know of. If you can then that means you can filter through the list and **only start* showing friends as soon as the user has entered at least 2 characters. The friend list reduces to a significant amount when you filter the friends list based on matching against the first two characters of each friend's name in the array.

Comment: Thanks again Pavan. You have to do the multiple searches (http api call) to get a simple array of friends. it can not be that fast while users are typing..